# How to prove that $\vartheta(x)=x+O(\frac x{\log(x)})$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> Suppose that we have $\pi(x)\log(x)=x+O(\frac x{\log(x)})$. I want to prove that $\vartheta(x)=\sum_\limits{p\le x}\log(p)=x+O(\frac x{\log(x)})$.

I've used the relation $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)\log (x)-\vartheta(x)}{x}=0$. So given $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N>0$ such that for all $x\ge N$

$$-\epsilon x<\pi(x)\log (x)-\vartheta(x)<\epsilon x$$

or

$$-\epsilon x<\pi(x)\log (x)-x+x-\vartheta(x)<\epsilon x$$

Since $\pi(x)\log(x)=x+O(\frac x{\log(x)})$, there exists some $M>0$ such that for all $x\ge 2$,

$$-M\frac x{\log(x)}\le\pi(x)\log(x)-x\le M\frac x{\log(x)}$$
Thus we have

$$-\epsilon x+\vartheta(x)-x\le\pi(x)\log(x)-x\le M\frac x{\log(x)}$$

and

$$-M\frac x{\log(x)}\le\pi(x)\log(x)-x\le\epsilon x+\vartheta(x)-x$$

So taking $\epsilon\to0$, implies that

$$-M\frac x{\log(x)}\le\vartheta(x)-x\le M\frac x{\log(x)}$$ or $\vartheta(x)-x=O(\frac x{\log(x)})$. But this is for all $x\ge N$ and not for $x\ge 2$. So I want to know if there is a way to eliminate this problem? Could anyone give me some suggestion, please?

---

I've also tried to solve the problem like below

$$\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\le x}\log(p)\le\sum_{p\le x}\log(x)=\pi(x)\log(x)=x+O(\frac x{\log(x)})$$

But I couldn't prove that

$$\vartheta(x)\ge x+O(\frac x{\log(x)}).$$

Comment: It would be better if you put the definition of $\vartheta$ in the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: by the [Abel summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) $$\theta\left(x\right)=\pi\left(x\right)\log\left(x\right)-\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\pi\left(t\right)}{t}dt.$$

Comment: As you probably know, if I use the Abel summation formula, then it would be the problem 4.19 in Apostol's analytic number theory. But my question is the problem 4.18. So I'm looking for another method.

Comment: @user604594 Except the equivalent [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), there is no other method